# Why does this term of two electron masses appear when calculating the heat of these nuclear decay modes?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Consider the following two nuclear decay modes:

$$^{64}_{29}\mathrm{Cu} \to e^- + \bar{\nu}_e + ^{64}_{30}\mathrm{Zn} $$

$$^{64}_{29}\mathrm{Cu} \to e^+ + \nu_e + ^{64}_{28}\mathrm{Ni}$$

The solutions I'm given calculate $Q$ using the mass excess of each nuclei. For the first decay mode (measuring mass in keV):

$$Q=\Delta M(^{64}_{29}\mathrm{Cu}) -\Delta M(^{64}_{30}\mathrm{Zn}) = 578,7 \ \mathrm{keV}$$

But for the second decay mode, an extra term involving the electron mass appears:

$$Q=\Delta M(^{64}_{29}\mathrm{Cu}) -\Delta M(^{64}_{28}\mathrm{Ni}) - 2m_ec^2 = 653,11 \ \mathrm{keV}$$

Why does this term appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the conventions for defining masses.

The Copper's mass is calculated with the 29 electrons that comes along with it. The mass of the Zinc is calculated with the 30 electrons that goes along with it. But the original Copper only had 29 electrons. This means that the emitted electron's mass is already accounted for in the Zinc's mass, so you cannot add that again. It would have been double-counting.

In the latter case, the Nickel only had 28 electron masses added to it. This means that you have to manually account for not just the positron's mass, but also an extra electron's mass that is not accounted for. So that is why you have $2m_ec^2$